# Aspire one 722 graphics driver installation boots and freezes to blank screen?

Tags: graphics

- Acer Aspire 722 - Dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 inside windows 7.

As I have updated my Ubuntu 12.04 and installed the restricted hardware (graphics) drivers, the system boots and freezes to a blank screen.

A hard reset is the only option to reboot.

Comment: Do you still experience this problem?

Comment: OP last seen half an hour later, voting to close OT/not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get to the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>? If so login to the console and uninstall the drivers by typing:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx fglrx-amdccclete
```

This will remove the AMD/ATI graphics driver and revert back to the open source one. The reboot the computer by typing

```
sudo reboot
```

If you cannot get to the console, choose recovery mode at the boot loader (GRUB) menu. [using this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). Then choose "Drop to root shell prompt." There you can use the above commands without `sudo` in the beginning.

Hope this helps